# google chrome does not detect system dark theme in Fedora 36 with Gnome

Tags: google-chrome, gnome

I'm using Fedora 36, which has default Gnome desktop environment. I have dark theme turned on in Gnome settings -> Appearance (NOT gnome tweaks). When I open firefox, it automatically detects my system dark, and when I go to google search in firefox, it properly appears as dark. I'm not even logged in.

However, when I use Google chrome, it does not properly detect system theme. It still appears white when I go to google search. Anything I have to manually do to get Google chrome working as well as firefox here?

**EDIT** same exact thing happens in Debian 11. Firefox works perfectly for auto-detecting device theme for dark mode; Chrome does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently this is [a known bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903).

> Issue 998903: Dark Gtk theme does not affect prefers-color-scheme media query
> Still matches 'light' even if the UI instance for NativeThemeGtk renders a dark UI.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not implemented yet to work with new Gnome API. You can use temporarily workaround, i wrote shell script file (run with sudo):

```
sed -i 's/^Exec=\/usr\/bin\/google-chrome-stable$/& --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode/' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
sed -i 's/%U/--enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode &/' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Edit for Chromium users:

```
sed -i 's/^Exec=\/usr\/bin\/google-chrome-stable$/& --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode/' /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
sed -i 's/%U/--enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode &/' /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
```

Comment: If you don't have sudo rights or don't want to change files belonging to an RPM package you can simply create a drop-in in your `$HOME`: `sed 's/%U/--enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode &/' /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop > ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` That way the work-around is also stable over chromium/chrome package updates.

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround add to `~/.config/chrome-flags.conf`

```
--enable-features=WebUIDarkMode,CSSColorSchemeUARendering
--force-dark-mode
```

This will force dark mode only for chrome's setting pages.

Comment: The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chromium#Making_flags_persistent) describes this config file for Chrome and analogously `~/.config/chromium-flags.conf` for Chromium. However, the Fedora 37 chromium doesn't try to read any `*flags.conf` (I've straced it). Perhaps this is an Arch-only feature?

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora you can open: `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` and enable that **Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents** option.
Then on `chrome://settings/appearance` ensure GTK+ option is active.
Maybe it works for other distributions Gnome 42, I'm gonna appreciate your comments.

Comment: This doesn't change the evaluation of `prefers-color-scheme` [CSS media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) expressions. I.e., as of 2023-02/Fedora 37, Chromium evaluates `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light)  { ...}` as matching by default and still after enabling the 'Auto Dark Mode'. This mode indeed changes the background to dark and uses a light font color - but it works more like the Dark-Reader addon, i.e. it comes up with some dark scheme on its own instead of relying on the sites CSS supporting dark mode via CSS media selectors.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Until there's no "official" solution I'll need to keep on some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically use the dark/light mode based on your gnome theme settings, then you can run the following.

```sh
google-chrome-stable $(echo $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme) $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme) | grep -vq dark || echo --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode)
```

or if you're using chromium . . .

```sh
chromium $(echo $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme) $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme) | grep -vq dark || echo --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode)
```